# Python: Preceder el trabajo de los hilos con un sleep hará que la salida de datos sea desordenada

Tags: python, date, hilos

Siento si el título no es muy descriptivo, pero para que se entienda mejor mi duda pongo el siguiente código:

```
import threading
import time

lock = threading.Lock()

def funcion(i):
    global lock
    time.sleep(1)     # Esta
    lock.acquire()    # Y esta
    print(f"Hilo {i} trabajando")
    lock.release()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    hilos = []
    for i in range(20):
        hilo = (threading.Thread(target=funcion, args=[i + 1]))
        hilos.append(hilo)
        hilo.start()

    for i in range(20):
        hilos[i].join()

    print("El programa ha finalizado")
```

El código anterior mostrará una salida con los hilos desordenados, pero si intercambio las dos lineas comentadas, la salida es ordenada.

La lógica (y la ignorancia) me dicen que en ambos casos la salida de datos debería ser ordenada, puesto que el primero en llegar al sleep será el primero en abandonarlo, y por mucho que investigo no alcanzo a comprender por qué esto es así.

Algunos compañeros de clase dicen que es por la imprecisión del sleep, que en unos casos dura ligeramente más o menos que en otros, y por otro lado me dicen que el sleep actúa como una sala de espera para los hilos y a partir de ahí el sistema operativo es quien decide qué hilo trabajará en cada situación, cosa que también va en contra de mi intuición.

En fin...si alguien fuera tan amable de explicarme este comportamiento...

Muchas gracias!!